# How to change default page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm super new to asp.net and I would like to know how to change the default page that is created in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHOA5.png).

Comment: also in the design part everytime i hover over it shows a cancel type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master page is /Views/Shared/_Layout .cshtml

Comment: Ty ,i just found it before reading this ,do you have any tips for a noob like me in asp?

Comment: You should try to follow some tutorials or read some [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942068/best-resources-books-for-asp-net-mvc-framework). There are also some very good free video tutorials by pluralsight: [MVC4](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m1-intro&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building) and [MVC5](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m1-introduction&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)

Comment: @Jaimecruz PRO AP.NET MVC 5 By Adam Freeman , PRO ASP.NET MVC 5 BY Galloway and Wilson, DB First Tutorial, Code First tutorial on msdn